# I'm trying to resize the ImageIcon and it's partially off the screen... How can I fix this?

Tags: java, image, resize

So... I'm trying to resize a happy face image:
[image]

It displays okay on the frame, but then I realized that part of it isn't shown. What I mean is that it's not resized, it's just cut off. Then I added some resizing code (which is all over the place and pretty much the same thing on every site) and it turns out that it doesn't work.

In other words, I get this.
[image]
What, if anything, is wrong here?
Thanks!

```
public class RockPaperScissors {

//global resources
final static Dimension SCREEN_SIZE = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
final static int WIDTH = (int) SCREEN_SIZE.getWidth();
final static int HEIGHT = (int) SCREEN_SIZE.getHeight();
final static ImageIcon RPS_LOGO = new ImageIcon("images/rps.png");


/**
 * @param args
 */
public RockPaperScissors() {

    ImageIcon icon = RPS_LOGO;
    Image img = icon.getImage(); 
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); 
    Graphics g = bi.createGraphics(); 
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, HEIGHT, HEIGHT, null); 
    ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon(bi);
    JLabel RPS_LOGO_LABEL = new JLabel(newIcon);

    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setName("Rock, Paper, Scissors!");
    window.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container frameContents = window.getContentPane();
    frameContents.setLayout(null);
    frameContents.add(RPS_LOGO_LABEL);
    Rectangle logo = new Rectangle(0,0,HEIGHT,HEIGHT);
    RPS_LOGO_LABEL.setBounds(logo);

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new RockPaperScissors();
}

}
```

Comment: Is the image really necessary in order to answer the question?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ...what? I put it there to show what's wrong with its placing on the frame. I just want to know what's wrong with the code...

Comment: I mean, the big round face is more than half of the content on your question...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza true, i'll make it smaller :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`getScaledInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29):

```
Image scaled = image.getScaledInstance(width, height, 5);
```

This code should scale the image to fit your entire frame.

Comment: What I tried was to make the dimensions HEIGHT, HEIGHT so it fits the frame with only space on the side... but I'll try it :)

Comment: Wait, what variable is `image`? Is it `img`?

Comment: Yes, it was just an example.